# error: Table may not exist or is unsupported relation type code: 25350 context: query: 0 location: mysqlclient.cpp:255 process: padbmaster [pid=15091]

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, schema, amazon-rds

We are trying to create a AWS Redshift EXTERNAL_SCHEMA from MySQL RDS but running into a strange problem. We followed the AWS instruction to create a Secret in Secret Manager with the RDS credentials and created an IAM user to access the Secret. We were able to get all the RDS table [schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzzF7.png) but we start running into problem when we try to [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzIht.png) the data inside of the EXTERNAL_SCHEMA. The [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWBOF.png) we are running into shows that the table does not exist or is unsupported data type.

We tried turning on the enhanced VPC option but didn't have any luck and trying to see if anybody else ever ran into this problem.

Please let us know if anybody was able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;
and Columns names and table names should be in double quotes

Answer (score 0):

change the table name in lower case. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).